# Why didn't the dynamic binding behave as expected?

Tags: c++, inheritance, dynamic-binding

Given the base and derived classes as below:

The base:

```
class AA
{
public:
    AA() = default;
    virtual void print() const { std::cout << aa << "\n";}

private:
    std::string aa = "AA";
};
```

The derived:

```
class BB : public AA
{
public:
    BB() = default;
    virtual void print() const override {std::cout << bb << "\n"; }

private:
    std::string bb = "BB";
};
```

The first try:

```
int main()
{
    AA aa;  BB bb;
    AA& //r = aa; r.print();

    r = bb;
    r.print();

    return 0;
}
```

The outcome was exactly what I had expected:

```
BB
Press <RETURN> to close this window...
```

But the second try when `//` was removed:

```
int main()
{
    AA aa;  BB bb;
    AA& r = aa; r.print();

    r = bb;
    r.print();
 //!^^^^^^^^^^--why wasn't the print in derived class called?
    return 0;
}
```

The output was:

```
AA
AA
Press <RETURN> to close this window...
```

As commented above, why wasn't the `print` defined in the derived class called when executing the second `r.print()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the expression `r = bb` is exactly equivalent to `aa = bb`. The assignment operator merely copies the parts of `bb` known to the `AA` class into the `aa` object.

In other words, after the assignment, `r` still points to `aa`, which is an instance of `AA`. It does *not* point to a `BB` instance in any sense.

A reference can never change which object it refers to, so the expected behavior cannot be achieved with references. To get the polymorphism you're looking for, you muse use pointers:

```
AA* p = &aa;
p->print();

p = &bb;
p->print();
```

Comment: So actually the statement `r = bb` has changed value of `aa` by copying the sub--object of object `bb` to it,hasn't it?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the "subject of object" terminology, but yes: `r = bb` simply runs `aa.AA::operator=(bb)`, which in turn copies the `AA`-parts of `bb` into `AA`.

Comment: sorry for my silly spelling, I should have written as subobject..and don't know why I cannot at your name user4815162342..

Comment: @Alan.W You cannot add the notification to me because it's unnecessary — since you're commenting my answer, I get automatically notified.

Comment: This is why you usually disable assignment when a class is designed to be used as a base.

Answer (score 1):

Because of this:

```
r = bb;
```

The above statement does not bind (rebind?) the reference `r` to `bb`. Instead, it copies the `AA` parts of `bb` into `aa` which is the object referred to by `r`.

To test the above claim, here is an example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/00d20990fe0ddd26

Comment: @Alan.W It's quite the "standard" online compiler here in [tag:C++], though you could find more in the [C++ wiki page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/info).